# Support with sql join statement

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am a student new to sql and Oracle Apex. Initially, I was given this working snippet:

```
SELECT Contract_no, customer_code, Start_Date, End_Date
FROM Contract
```

I attempted to add this code to it:

```
INNER JOIN Customer
ON Contract.customercode = Customer.Customername
```

Upon adding my code, I received an Oracle / PLSQL: ORA-06550 Error Message, which stated:

> Invalid user.table.column, or column specification.

I am trying to add Customer Name, from the customer table, to the contract table by using the JOIN statement.

I basically have 2 tables: `Contract` and `Customer`.

`Customer` contains the following columns

- Customer Code
- Customer Name
- Address
- Postcode
- Telephone

`Contract` contains the following columns

- Contract No
- Customer Code
- Start Date
- END date

Comment: i'm confused. is the column name `customer_code` or `customercode` or `Customer Code`?

Comment: Answering the question by @Aツ  will probably solve this error.

Comment: on the interface it's called customer Code, however whenever I click on the Contract page. There is a SQL query. pre-populated with this code: SELECT Contract_no, customer_code, Start_Date, End_Date
FROM Contract

Comment: @SaliwarriorAl-Sahli Does the pre-populated code work before you add anything? I would assume yes, but your post doesn't clearly say.

Comment: @wirefox Yes. it works before i add anything

Answer (score 1):

Your second sample's field names are wrong.

`Contract.customercode` should be `Contract.customer_code`, and if the naming conventions in your database are consistent then `Customer.Customername` should be `Customer.customer_name`. However, you probably don't want to use customer_name. Given that both tables contain customer_code fields, you probably meant to join based on those. Joining records where someone's name is the same as their code is unlikely to produce good results.

So your last line would be

```
ON Contract.customer_code = Customer.customer_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT Contract_no, customer_code, Start_Date, End_Date
FROM Contract
INNER JOIN Customer
ON Contract.customer_code = Customer.customer_code
```

Make sure you're joining your primary key on the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a space in one of the the column names.
Please post the column definition using the DESC  command.
If there were spaces, you'd need to refer such column with quotes throughout your code, which is not really ideal to use.
Oracle does not recommend quoted identifiers, so please do not allow space in column names.
Please use an alias to identify the column name in the select statement and also use consistent column names throughout the query.
This will help in code maintenance and better readability of code.

Below is a small piece of code i tried for your reference.

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
customer_code VARCHAR2(10),
customer_name  VARCHAR2(10),
address        VARCHAR2(100),
postcode       VARCHAR2(10),
telephone      VARCHAR2(10));


CREATE TABLE contract(
contract_no     NUMBER, 
customer_code   VARCHAR2(10), 
start_date      DATE,
end_date        DATE
);


INSERT INTO customer
values ('1','Person 1','Address 1','12345A','0000000000');

INSERT INTO contract
VALUES(1,'1','01-JAN-2010','31-DEC-2019');

SELECT con.contract_no, cust.customer_code, con.start_date, con.end_date
FROM contract con
INNER JOIN customer cust
ON con.customer_code = cust.customer_code;

Output:
CONTRACT_NO CUSTOMER_C START_DAT END_DATE 
----------- ---------- --------- ---------
          1 1          01-JAN-10 31-DEC-19
```

HTH